# условие в переменной

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, как вставить условие в переменной? 
Пробовал сделать так

```
$per = "<div>
".
if (1 == 1) {
  ."Удачно".
} else {
  ."Не удачно".
}
."
</div>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте тернарный оператор:

```
$per = "<div>\n" . (1 === 1 ? "Удачно" : "Не удачно") . "\n</div>";
```

https://repl.it/Cnj3/0

Comment: @СашаОсипов, замените слово `Удачно` на HTML картинки. И всё.

Comment: @СашаОсипов, вот так - https://repl.it/Cnj3/1

Comment: @СашаОсипов, как у Вас с ошибкой код не вылетел? `$post[$photo]`.

Comment: Всё уже, решил проблему.

Comment: а как вставить такое условие? 
`($_GET[id] == $iduser) OR ($type == $iduser) OR ($iduser == $idUserp)`

Comment: 1) `$id`. 2) Обернуть всё условие скобками и поставить на место условия в тернарном операторе. Хотя сложные условия лучше-таки через обычный `if` делать - чтобы не марать код.

Comment: а можно код? Не очень понял вас

Comment: @СашаОсипов https://repl.it/Cnj3/2

Comment: ой, точно, забыл в скобки условие поставить

Answer (score 1):

```
$per1 = "Неудачно";
if (1 == 1) {
  $per1 = ."Удачно".
}
$per = "<div>".$per1."</div>";
```

или

```
$per = "<div>".((1 == 1)? "Удачно" : "Неудачно")."</div>";
```

Comment: Нет, нужно, чтобы прямо в перменной находилось условие

Comment: "прямо в перменной находилось" - потрудитесь объяснить, что это значит.

Comment: Копировать не хорошо)